# Dropwizard / Jersey HTTP Servlet Connection Reset but Jersey Resource is fine

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, dropwizard

I implemented an API using Jersey Resources and `environment.servlets().addServlet(newServlet)` to see which one would be faster.

Both do the exact same thing. But when I run AB benchmarking on the two implementations, using Jersey Resource works fine but with Servlet I get `apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)`.

This only happens when hitting with concurrent requests:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 100 -k -T application/binary -p req.bin http://localhost:8142/
```

Any idea why Servlet would have this issue? (the reason I want to use servlet is the data I am posting is raw binary and its easier to handle it there using the Input/Output Stream.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It was due to Keep Alive connections, I needed to set the Content-Length header in the response.

```
        response.setContentLength(out.len());
        response.getOutputStream().write(out.get(), 0, out.len());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

And not call `response.getOutputStream().close()`